# If the Scarlet Witch wears the Ant-Man suit, will her powers become stronger as her physical size increases?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame,* during the Battle of Earth, Scott Lang used the Ant-Man suit to grow to about 50 feet tall and was strong enough to punch a Chitauri attack ship and knock it out of commission.

In a scenario in which Scott had been unable to make it to the Battle of Earth and had decided to give the Ant-Man suit to the Scarlet Witch so she could use it, after she had grown to 50 feet tall, would her increased physical size have resulted in her having much stronger magical powers?

Comment: Your last paragraph is a distinct question so I have edited it out.

Comment: This is attracting close votes due to the speculative wording in the question. However, we have enough information at present to make an answer for this as I have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They would be the same, Pym Particles only alter the distance between atoms and increase density and strength. Wanda's powers are all mental and so altering strength and distance between atoms shouldn't affect her powers.

> **Darren Cross:** When I took over this company for Dr. Pym, I immediately started researching a particle that could change the distance between atoms while increasing density and strength. Why this revolutionary idea remained buried beneath the dust and cobwebs of Hank’s research, I couldn’t tell you.
>
> [...]
>
> **Dr. Hank Pym:** Twenty years ago I created a formula that altered atomic relative distance.
>
> **Scott Lang:** Huh?
>
> **Dr. Hank Pym:** I learned how to change the distance between atoms, that’s what powers the suit, that’s why it works.
>
> <sub>*Ant-Man*</sub>

> **Maria Hill:** He's got increased metabolism and improved thermal homeostasis. Her thing is neural electric interfacing, telekinesis, mental manipulation.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>